# Proper word wrapping of long text

Tags: python

I have a 1000 character long text string and I want to split this text in chunks smaller than 100 characters without splitting a whole word (99 characters are fine but 100 not). The wrapping/splitting should only be made on whitespaces:

Example:

```
text = "... this is a test , and so on..."
                              ^
                  #position: 100
```

should be splitted to:

```
newlist = ['... this is a test ,', ' and so on...', ...]
```

I want to get a list `newlist` of the text splitted properly into readable (not word-cropped) chunks. How would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module's [wrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) function. The below example splits the lines 10 characters wide:

```
In [1]: import textwrap

In [2]: textwrap.wrap("... this is a test , and so on...", 10)
Out[2]: ['... this', 'is a test', ', and so', 'on...']
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't know there was such a module. I was just sitting on a complicated peace of code:)

Comment: @Johnny Haha been there myself don't worry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap) module:

```
In [2]: import textwrap

In [3]: textwrap.wrap("""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   ...: tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   ...: quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   ...: consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   ...: cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
   ...: proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        """, 40)
Out[3]: 
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur',
 'adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor',
 'incididunt ut labore et dolore magna',
 'aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis',
 'nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris',
 'nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit',
 'in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu',
 'fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint',
 'occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in',
 'culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim',
 'id est laborum.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordwrap like the other guys said, however for an alternative option:

```
def splitter(s, n):
    for start in range(0, len(s), n):
        yield s[start:start+n]

data = "abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij"
for splitee in splitter(data, 10):
    print splitee
```

Comment: "The wrapping/splitting should only be made on whitespaces" [...] "properly into readable (not word-cropped) chunks".